# Index Error: List Index out of Range in Python 3 for Specific Test Cases Even After Making Corner Cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, runtime-error, testcase

I was trying to solve a problem in **Python** and faced some issues with a specific set of test case that are:

```
5

qwertyuioplkjhgfdsazxcvbnm

aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

aaaabbbbbbbaaaabbbbbbaaaab

zszsdasldnaosdihafalsssadf

jdflsddjddjlasdjsasjsjssjs
```

My code was:

```
tc = int(input())
for tc_ct in range(tc):
    s = input()
    edited_s = []
    for elm in s:
        edited_s.append(elm)
    if len(set(edited_s)) == 1 and len(edited_s) > 1:
        for output in set(edited_s):
            print(output)
    else:    
        n = len(edited_s)
        for i in range(n-1):
            if i < n-1 and s[i] == s[i+1]:
                    del edited_s[i]
        print("".join(edited_s))
```

Surprisingly this error came up for a few test cases not all of them, because index errors usually come up everytime rather than once in a while. Any help from other Pythoners is appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Answer (score 0):

Your program dedups consecutive characters in a word.

You're running into errors in the `else-statement` because you're deleting items in a list while also reading it in the same loop.

Thus the size of the list is changing after a pass of the loop where a character is deleted from it.

You can work around this by making a copy of the list, one for iterating and another for deleting items from.

However, I recommend making a result list and adding to it incrementally.
In the `else-statement` of your `if-expression`, you can make a list.

Only add a character in this list when the previously added character in the
list is not the current one.

```py
dedup_word = [None,] 

word = input()

for current_entry in word:
    previous_entry = dedup_word[-1]
    if previous_entry != current_entry:
        dedup_word.append(current_entry)

output = ''.join(filter(None, dedup_word))
print(output)
```

You could even refactor your current program and have the body of the `else-statement` be the main program after reading your input.